# NSPredicate: NSLog of predicate using NSDate seems wrong

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate, unix-timestamp

Where is my error?

Following lines of code:

```
NSPredicate* someTestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"departureTime >= %@", [NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Some Test Predicate: %@", someTestPredicate);
```

Results in:

```
2019-04-02 20:19:55.671894+0200 [9402:337625] Some Test Predicate: departureTime >= CAST(575921995.671820, "NSDate")
```

And this timestamp refers to:
04/01/1988 @ 6:19pm (UTC)

So why is the year so wrong? What do I do wrong?

Comment: This is basically a repost of a portion of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477111/nsdate-timezones-and-unix-timestamp-confusion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is correct, but the internal reference date used by NSDate is 2001-01-01, not 1970-01-01 as seen in many other places for UNIX timestamps. That's also why NSDate has [timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate?language=objc) and [timeIntervalSince1970](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970?language=objc).

Answer (score 2):

`NSDate`'s epoch is not the same as the Unix epoch. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate):

> Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

So, 575921995.671820 seconds from 2001/01/01 is 2019-04-02 18:19:55 UTC.